# Given the interval values $s^2$ between pairs of events, and given coordinates of these events, how to evaluate the components of the metric tensor?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

Considering a suitable set $\mathcal S$ of events in a flat region of spacetime,
given for all pairs of these events the corresponding [interval values, $s^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime#Spacetime_intervals_in_flat_space)$ : \mathcal S \times \mathcal S \rightarrow \mathbb R ~ \text m^2 $,
(where "$\text m$" denotes a suitable dimensionful quantity: "[1 meter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre)"),
and given some (particular, admissable) assignment of coordinates $f : \mathcal S \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$ to these events,
where $f[~\mathsf E~] \mapsto \{~\theta[~\mathsf E~], \xi[~\mathsf E~], \upsilon[~\mathsf E~], \zeta[~\mathsf E~]~\}$ for every event $\mathsf E \in \mathcal S$,
how to evaluate the corresponding 10 [components of the metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Metric_in_coordinates) at event $\mathsf E$
(values $g_{\theta \theta}[~\mathsf E~], g_{\theta \xi}[~\mathsf E~], g_{\theta \upsilon}[~\mathsf E~], g_{\theta \zeta}[~\mathsf E~], g_{\xi \xi}[~\mathsf E~], g_{\xi \upsilon}[~\mathsf E~], g_{\xi \zeta}[~\mathsf E~], g_{\upsilon \upsilon}[~\mathsf E~],g_{\upsilon \zeta}[~\mathsf E~], $ and $g_{\zeta \zeta}[~\mathsf E~]$)
?

Answer (score -1):

For some coordinate assignment $f : \mathcal S \rightarrow \mathbb R^4$ to be admissible, it must be invertible, i.e. $f^{(-1)} : \mathbb R^4 \leftarrow \mathcal S$ must be a function as well.

Using this inverse function $f^{(-1)}$ allows to express explicitly

$g_{\theta \theta}[~\mathsf E~] := {\text{lim}}_{\{\epsilon_{\theta} \rightarrow 0\}}\big[~ {\text{lim}}_{\{\delta_{\theta} \rightarrow 0\}}[~$
$\frac{
s^2[~f^{(-1)}[~f[~\mathsf E~] + \{~\epsilon_{\theta}, 0, 0, 0~\}~], f^{(-1)}[~f[~\mathsf E~] + \{~\delta_{\theta}, 0, 0, 0~\}~]~] - 
s^2[~f^{(-1)}[~f[~\mathsf E~] + \{~\epsilon_{\theta}, 0, 0, 0~\}~], \mathsf E~] -
s^2[~f^{(-1)}[~f[~\mathsf E~] + \{~\delta_{\theta}, 0, 0, 0~\}~], \mathsf E~]
}{2~\epsilon_{\theta}~\delta_{\theta}}~]   ~\big],$

$g_{\theta \xi}[~\mathsf E~] := {\text{lim}}_{\{\epsilon_{\theta} \rightarrow 0\}}\big[~ {\text{lim}}_{\{\delta_{\xi} \rightarrow 0\}}[~$
$\frac{
s^2[~f^{(-1)}[~f[~\mathsf E~] + \{~\epsilon_{\theta}, 0, 0, 0~\}~], f^{(-1)}[~f[~\mathsf E~] + \{~0, \delta_{\xi}, 0, 0~\}~]~] - 
s^2[~f^{(-1)}[~f[~\mathsf E~] + \{~\epsilon_{\theta}, 0, 0, 0~\}~], \mathsf E~] -
s^2[~f^{(-1)}[~f[~\mathsf E~] + \{~0, \delta_{\xi}, 0, 0~\}~], \mathsf E~]
}{2~\epsilon_{\theta}~\delta_{\xi}}~]   ~\big],$

and so on.

As a further condition for the admissibility of the coordinate assignment $f$ it may be required that all these limits (derivatives) exist, and that the resulting values $g$ are independent of the order in which these limits are evaluated.